# Controlling image width, height, and placement in Hugo

Tags: html, css, hugo

I'm using Hugo to create a new blog site and am having trouble understanding how to control the image width, height, and location within a blog post written in Markdown and rendered with Blackfriday.

I tried injecting the following raw HTML into the post:

```
<img src="https://social-ruminations.typepad.com/.a/6a00e553d6f3d488330120a5b5862c970b-pi" style="margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px; float: left;" width="100" height="149" border="0" />
```

and yet the image still gets stretched to the full width of the post. Any ideas on how I can influence the rendering of the image in the post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be related to CSS precedence rules. If a style is defined for `img` somewhere else in the theme (e.g. `width: 100%`), it will take precedence over the width/height HTML attributes.

Some references:

- [Precedence in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/precedence-css-order-css-matters/)
- [Presentational Attributes vs Inline Styles](http://ashishuideveloper.in/2017/01/presentational-attributes-inline-styles/)

To overcome it with little change, you may try including those values as an inline style, as it usually takes precedence over the other cases (apart from `!important` directive).

Also worth specifying the units (e.g. `px`). If not, it's broken according to the standard, and the browser might not be able to guess the right thing.

```
<img src="..." 
     style="margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px; float: left; 
            width:100px; height:149px; border:0" />
```

Comment: Thanks @picadoh - you nailed it. This is what I ultimately discovered as well.